# Get previous month of a given date sql

Tags: sql

I had this:

```
select company
from alldata
where **{previous month of date("01.05.2011")}**
IN
(select month from alldata where SumNrSpot=0)
```

I need to find the previous month in the `where` clouse.
Please, anybody can help?

Answer (score 3):

In case you're using MySQL:

```
SELECT MONTH(DATE_SUB('2011-05-01', 1 MONTH))
```

in your case

```
select company
from alldata
where MONTH(DATE_SUB('2011-05-01', 1 MONTH))
IN
(select month from alldata where SumNrSpot=0)
```

Read more about both functions [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

You may use `DateAdd()` method with parameter, month, and `-1` as value to get previous month.

Following will give you

```
select DatePart(mm,DateAdd(m,-1,GetDate())) as PreviousMonth
```

For your query you can try:

```
select company 
from alldata
where datepart(mm,dateadd(m,-1,Convert(DateTime, Convert(DateTime,'01.05.2011',104))))
IN (select month from alldata where SumNrSpot=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

For **SQL Server**

You can just use the function [MONTH()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx) to get a month from a date.
You can use DATEADD(month,-1,) to adjust a date by a month.
You should always use the format YYYYMMDD if you present dates to SQL Server in textual form.

```
where MONTH(DATEADD(month,-1,'20110501') IN
```

That's assuming the table column `alldata.month` contains a numeric value of the month from 1-12.

Comment: You are suggesting `DATEADD(month,-1,...)` in the beginning, but your example shows `DATEADD(month,1,...)`. And by the way, they may be using MySQL, judging by the `date(...)` and the double quotes around the date.

Answer (score 0):

extract  month from given date  and add -1

```
select ( extract (month from now()) -1 ) as previous_month
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
DATEPART(mm,(DATEADD(m,-1,CONVERT(DATETIME,'01.05.2011')))) AS PreviousMonth
IN 
(Select month from alldata where SumNrSpot=0)
```

Assuming your "Month" column is an integer value

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
select company
from alldata
where MONTH(`Mon`) -1
IN
(select MONTH(Mon) from alldata where SumNrSpot=0)
```

Thanks anyway, some of your responses was useful and appreciated.